# Trying to create a new Active Directory user, Invoke(“SetPassword”,pwd) Sharepoint 2013

Tags: c#, sharepoint

this my Code , whene i run it in console application its works but whene a create a webpart for sharepoint its returns an exception 403 forbidden the exception throws at line 
  user.Invoke("SetPassword", new object[] { "password" });

```
          user = Ldap.Children.Add("cn=username", "user");
        user.Properties["SAMAccountName"].Add("username");
        user.Properties["sn"].Add("userfn");
        user.Properties["givenName"].Add("userln");


        user.CommitChanges();
       user.Invoke("SetPassword", new object[] { "password" });
        // On va maintenant activer le compte : ADS_UF_NORMAL_ACCOUNT
        user.Properties["userAccountControl"].Value = 0x0200;

        // On envoie les modifications au serveur
        user.CommitChanges();
```